# React-Three-Fiber: how to use setViewOffset

Tags: reactjs, typescript, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am using React-Three-Fiber in an application written in typescript. I have set up my canvas and camera but I need to implement [.setViewOffset](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=cam#api/en/cameras/OrthographicCamera.setViewOffset) on my orthographic camera. On the three.js docs it states the input for setViewOffset is:

`( fullWidth : Float, fullHeight : Float, x : Float, y : Float, width : Float, height : Float ) : null`

My setup:

```
<Canvas orthographic camera={{ zoom: 50, position: [0, 100, 100], setViewOffset: SVO }}>
 <ambientLight intensity={1.90} color={"rgb(255,255,255)"}/>
 <directionalLight position={[150, 250, -150]} castShadow={true}/>
 <Box position={[0, 0, 0]} color="red"/>
 <Box position={[0, 7, 0]} color="blue"/>
 <Box position={[0, -7, 0]} color="green"/>
</Canvas>
```

I've tried implementing the following for variable "SVO":

```
const SVO = [ 500, 500, 1000, 0, 500, 500 ];
//Typescript error:
//Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '((fullWidth: number, fullHeight: number, x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number) => void) & ((fullWidth: number, fullHeight: number, offsetX: number, offsetY: number, width: number, height: number) => void)'


const SVO = {fullWidth: 50, fullHeight: 50, offsetX: 50, offsetY: 50, width: 50, height: 50};
//Typescript error:
//Type '{ fullWidth: number; fullHeight: number; offsetX: number; offsetY: number; width: number; height: number; }' is not assignable to type '((fullWidth: number, fullHeight: number, x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number) => void) & ((fullWidth: number, fullHeight: number, offsetX: number, offsetY: number, width: number, height: number) => void)'.


const SVO = ( fullWidth=500, fullHeight=500, offsetX=1000, offsetY=-1000, width=500, height=500 ) => { };
//Accepted by typescript but has no effect.
```

This is my first time using Typescript and react-three-fiber so I don't really know what structure it's expecting me to give it for setViewOffset. Hence why I tried an array, object and function. I've implemented setViewOffset in other projects using vanilla three.js like so:

```
const [ w, h, cam, frust ] = [ this.mount.clientWidth, this.mount.clientHeight, this.camera, this.frustumSize ];
cam.setViewOffset( w, h, -225, -120, w, h);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the answer lies in the onUpdate prop using @react-three/drei cameras

```
import { OrthographicCamera  } from '@react-three/drei'
```

...

```
<OrthographicCamera onUpdate={c => c.setViewOffset(...) />
```